# Why did this designer decouple to PE-ground?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, decoupling-capacitor

I'm reading a schematic from a Commodore 128-computer. The schematic is designed in 1985 and contains a detail I've never seen before.

The picture shows the primary stage prior the transformer. L1 and C1 is a pretty standard EMI-filter, but C2 and C3 decouples the AC-lines to PE. I have never seen this before. I showed this to an electrician and an electronics guy, but none of them has seen it as well.

I don't remember the value of L1, but C1 = 0.1uF and C2 = C3 = 2.2nF.

Why are C2/C3 decoupled to PE? Why are they there, what are their purpose?

[image]

Comment: Uhm, where else to decouple to than earth? If you google image search for mains emi filter, then you will find all kinds of them that do it that or similar way, even most IEC receptable filter modules have similar caps in a similar configuration.

Comment: That looks like every mains line input filter I've ever seen ... Nothing unusual there.

Comment: As others have pointed out these capacitors are not unusual in EMI fillters. There are special requirements on these however since should they fail short circuit there is a safety risk so they must be approved Y' capacitors.. Also value must be small to limit earth current to a safe level.

Answer (score 2):

This was probably to meet RF EMI emission standards from the equipment back out of the mains lead. This prevents RF on the transformer with respect to case ground propagating along the mains lead with the supply cores and the PE core acting as a transmission line.

A more common way to improve this spec (likely as well as using C2,3) would be to connect the screen winding of the transformer (the vertical line between primary and secondary) to PE ground, to intercept most of the RF picked up by the power supply.

Comment: They may have also needed to be relativel small, because (at least in the US) there are rules about stored charge present at the plug terminals where hands can touch them, too.